# How to access document ID from firebase in flutter?

Tags: json, flutter, networking

I am working with flutter and firebase. 
I have a collection with a list of documents, and those documents further have many fields each. 
I have an API for accessing the documents, which returns a list of the details in each document. 
But, I want to access the document id of each document. How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

If you write such a query you can have every documentId of your documents.

```
_getDocuments() async {
await _firestore.collection("yourCollection").getDocuments().
then((myDocuments) {
  for (DocumentSnapshot eachDocument in myDocuments.documents) {
       print(eachDocument.documentID);
    } 
  }
});
```

}

Comment: The problem is I cannot access the database directly. I have to access using api

Comment: But you better clarify what you have done until now maybe you did not even add firebase package or google services json or... it should be more clear

Comment: Hey Shivanshi, have you figured out your problem yet?